# How to do join with multiple conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql, inner-join

How can i it in single query

Get mID for uID(1) (33,34,35)
select text where mID (33,34,35){based on the above result}
select Name where uID(user id of mID in table b (5,6)){based on the above result}

Output

```
txt1  user5
txt3  user6
```

The only id I know is uID. How to do this in a single query.

```
TableA       TableB                      TableC
uID  mID    mID   Text  uID             uID    Name
1    33      33   txt1   5               1     user1
2    34      34   txt2   5               2     user2
1    35      35   txt3   6               5     user5
2    33                                  6     user6
2    34
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select b.Text, c.Name
from TableA a
inner join TableB b on a.mID = b.mID
inner join TableC c on b.uID = c.uID
where a.uID = 1
```